Polars cannot infer date columns on DataFrame creation, but succeed in automatic casting afterwards
I have a list of dictionaries, results, with the following schema:
import polars as pl

results = ...
schema = {
    "id": pl.Int64,
    "title": pl.Utf8,
    "proprietors": pl.List(pl.Utf8)
    "registrationDate": pl.Date,
}

When I attempt to create a dataframe with the schema, it fails:
df = pl.DataFrame(results, schema=schema)

yields

ComputeError: could not append value: "2024-08-16T00:00:00" of type:
str to the builder; make sure that all rows have the same schema or
consider increasing infer_schema_length
it might also be that a value overflows the data-type's capacity

However, creating the DataFrame with the date columns set to the pl.Utf8 String datatype, then converting the date columns to pl.Date afterwards, works:
for col, dtype in schema.items():
    if col.endswith("Date"):
        schema[col] = pl.Utf8
df = pl.DataFrame(results, schema=schema)

for col, dtype in schema.items():
    if col.endswith("Date"):
        df = df.with_columns(pl.col(col).str.strptime(pl.Datetime))
# Succeeds, no errors

polars 1.6.0
python 3.12.4

Can you try df = pl.DataFrame(results, schema=schema, infer_schema_length=None)

@user459872 Same error

What else is in registrationDate? Can you share a runnable example with results?

this one definitely needs reproducible example

@RomanPekar I know, but I don't know how to find the offending column or values. Any hints?

Note, that in you conversion example you convert to pl.Datetime, while in your dataset creation example you use pl.Date.
On my machine it works fine for strings of "YYYY-MM-DD" format:
import polars as pl

results = {"id": [1,2], "registrationDate": ["2024-08-15", "2024-08-17"]}
schema = {
    "id": pl.Int64,
    "registrationDate": pl.Date,
}

print(pl.DataFrame(results, schema=schema))

┌─────┬──────────────────┐
│ id  ┆ registrationDate │
│ --- ┆ ---              │
│ i64 ┆ date             │
╞═════╪══════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 2024-08-15       │
│ 2   ┆ 2024-08-17       │
└─────┴──────────────────┘

